# INNER JOIN issue with list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I have a listview and when I call the SQL query inner join in the on create it doesn't do anything and also no errors occurred

```
        public Cursor getBankBranch() {
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DataEntry.BRANCH_TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN  " 
            + DataEntry.BANK_TABLE_NAME + " ON " 
            + DataEntry.BANK_TABLE_NAME + "." + DataEntry.COLUMN_BANK_ID + "  = " 
            + DataEntry.BRANCH_TABLE_NAME + "." + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_BANK_ID;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

this is the table's content

```
            String SQL_CREATE_BANK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DataEntry.BANK_TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BANK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BANK_NAME + " TEXT );";

    String SQL_CREATE_BRANCH_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DataEntry.BRANCH_TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_NAME + " TEXT , "
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_NUMBER + " TEXT , "
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
            + DataEntry.COLUMN_BRANCH_BANK_ID + " INTEGER );";

    // Execute the SQL statement
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_BANK_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_BRANCH_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just getting the cursor that points to the result set, then you move it to the first result after that you close it, but you don't actually use it.

the steps of getting it to work

make a select query

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT ..."
```

execute the query to get cursor

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

create a cursorAdapter

```
MyCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
```

set the adapter of the ListView

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[here is an example of how to use it](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

Comment: your analysing is 100% true I made the edit you wrote but the same the listview is viewing all the data as if we didn't add an inner join query

Comment: please add the contents of the 2 tables (bank, branch)

Comment: didn't you insert anything in them ?

Comment: thank you very much, the problem was that I was declaring getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this); at the end of the onCreate so I deleted it and the problem solved do you have a way to use it with the query you have given me it

Comment: Please can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/47943367/7994373 @minasameh